# Replacing all rows in a data frame starting with specific character with values stored in vector

Tags: r

I have a data frame (df) which looks like this:

```
df

    df$column1
>hg19_chr1:55343-67868
ATATGAGCGT
>hg19_chr6:343114-831443
GGGGCCGCGTGCTG
>hg19_chr15:76644-90990
TTTCATCAT
```

Then I have a vector (vec) with 3 character
"SRSF4", "MAX", "BIM"

I would like to replace all the rows of the data frame which starts with the character ">" with the name stored in the vector:

Output:

```
df

    df$column1
SRSF4
ATATGAGCGT
MAX
GGGGCCGCGTGCTG
BIM
TTTCATCAT
```

I wrote something like this but it does not seem to work:

```
data <- data.frame(lapply(df, function(x) {gsub(">.$ ", vec, x)}))
```

Any help highly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Please use `dput` to show the small example.  If it is a character column, then `i1 <- grep("^[>]", df$column1); df$column1[i1] <- vec`

Comment: yes, it is a character column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can create a logical vector and then do the replacement

```
i1 <- grep("^[>]", df$column1)
df$column1[i1] <- paste0(">", vec)
```

NOTE: Here, we are assuming that the `length` of the 'vec' and the number of rows that have `>` as starting character to be the same

Comment: @PaoloLorenzini. Just use `df$column1[i1] <- paste0(">", vec)`